# Fix element on window scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code achieves the effect, but is it a resource friendly way of doing it?

Just to clarify: target `div.fixMe` and fix it to the top of the window when the user scrolls past its natural position. (I do realise there are plugins to achieve this result, but I wanted to build it myself)

Is this the best way to achieve the desired result? Is it a good idea that the whole function triggers whenever the user scrolls, or should I be splitting up code?

```
(function() {
var fixedElement = $('.fixMe').offset(),
    scrolled = $(window).scroll(function() {
        var winScrolled = $(this).scrollTop();
        if(winScrolled > fixedElement.top - 10) {
            $('.fixMe').css({'position': 'fixed','top' : '10px'})
        }
        else {
            $('.fixMe').css({'position': 'static'})
        }
    });
})()
```

Any feedback/criticism is welcome. I should probably get/set the width of `div.fixMe` to avoid display issues.

Answer (score 3):

Two things I noticed/would recommend:

1. Cache jQuery variables such as $(this) and $('.fixMe') to prevent redundant lookups during each scroll event.
2. Implement an event debouncer/limiter, this is because the scroll event fires a lot more than you likely think it does. There are many utils/plugins to achieve this such as:

   - https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce
   - http://unscriptable.com/2009/03/20/debouncing-javascript-methods/
   - http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/

I even wrote a very simple one: http://limit.gotsomething.com/. My site will show you why debouncing/limiting is useful.

Other than that looks good to me!

cheers,
Marc.

Comment: Thanks Marc. While only recently making a concerted effort to learn JQuery I was conscious of many events firing. However if a project is of this scale, do I need to worry about this?

Comment: In reality your code does so little that there isn't a great need to deal with these performance enhancements. Just keep them in mind when you are triggering events or functions a lot and when the result if large iterations or heavy DOM manipulation.

Comment: Caching  `$('.fixme')` outside of the scroll event will be noticeable on IE at least. In IE7 on a decent sized page I think you might have trouble even scrolling the page by doing that lookup in the scroll event.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for this:

clone `<div>` element when original element reach the top of window on page-scroll.

```js
function divFloater(div){
    var win = $(window);
    var divTop = div.offset().top;
    var divLeft = div.offset().left;

    win.scroll(function(){  
        var has_fixed = div.children('div').hasClass('fixed');
        var winTop = win.scrollTop();
        if ((winTop > divTop) && !has_fixed){            
            div.clone().appendTo(div).addClass("fixed");
            $('.fixed').css({'left':divLeft+'px'}).fadeIn();
        } else if ((winTop <= divTop)){
            $('.fixed').fadeOut();
            div.children('.fixed').remove();
        }
//        console.log(winTop+'|'+divTop'|'+has_fixed+);
    }); 
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    var floating_div=$('.view-aktualis-palyazatok').children('.view-header');
    divFloater(floating_div);
});
```

CSS code for this

```
.view-header {
    position:relative;
}
.view-header.fixed {
    position:fixed;
    display:none;
    top: 0;
}
```

sandbox: http://jsfiddle.net/eapo/Djf3E/1/

Please feel free to catch bugs, and advices are welcome.